# What is the best way to catch isRead event for a mail with Microsoft graph API?

Tags: email, outlook, webhooks, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to catch the precise time when an email is read through Microsoft Graph API.

I tried :

- Microsoft Graph API webhooks : sends a notification to an URL when a message folder is updated (ie isRead event), which allows me to catch the email ID and the time the notification is sent. Problem : it seems not to catch every event. Marking 'read' several messages at the same time or quickly only ends with one call to the notification_url --> information is lost.
- Microsoft Graph API 'LastModifiedDate' : doesn't evolve with the 'read' event.
- Microsoft Graph API 'isRead' property : only set to true or false, doesn't give any information about time.
- Microsoft Graph API delta queries with 'isRead' : could work, but implies to constantly run the delta query. Isn't that a huge API load if you track a big number of email accounts ?

My question : is there anyway that could be more efficient and elegant to get these simple datas ?

Answer (score 1):

The date/time a given message is marked as read isn't available. It would also be extremely unreliable as messages can be switch between read and unread states at will. Polling the API would also present a challenge as you would likely end up having the connection throttled pretty quickly.

Comment: I understand, but why the webhooks aren't reliable enough ? Several isRead events could be enqueued so they call the notification URL, as many times as the number of events, so we don't miss any event.

Comment: Webhooks are great for telling you something changed so you know to check but they are not an event feed. If a batched set of events occurred, you will receive a single event. Otherwise my marking 40,000 messages read at once or empting my junk folder would just overwhelm the endpoint.

Comment: I understand your point. But without going towards 40 000 read events, we could imagine that the API would group several notifications in the webhook, avoiding sending more than 1 notification every X minute, but including several events in each. Thanks for your answer anyway !